# MAMP Apache document root keeps resetting

Tags: mamp

I have MAMP setup on Windows for localhost development.

And I'm pointing the Apache document root to a folder inside DropBox (for automatic backup of media files etc).

It works great, but each time I close and restart MAMP the Apache folder location gets reset to the default C:\MAMP\htdocs location.

So I have to go into the settings each time and point it to the correct DropBox folder location. How can I stop it from resetting each time?

Comment: I am having this same problem and can't find a solution. Are you using V3.2.2? I never had this issue in the previous version, so may be worth downgrading for now until somebody answers this question - that's what I'm going to do.